# Show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{(a_1 +1)\cdots(a_n +1)}=1-\frac1g$ where $g=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n(a_k+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Assume that $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n(a_k+1)= g$$ for some positive and finite $g$, then prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{(a_1 +1)....(a_n +1)}=1-\frac1g$$

I have tried $u_n/u_{n+1}$ but its not working then I have tried $$\lim(a_n +1-1)/(a_1+1)....(a_n+1)=1/(a_1 +1)...(a_(n-1) + 1) - 1/g$$ then I am stuck.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please check my edit also correct the other expressions it is not clear what you are asking or what you are stating.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is that every partial sum can be computed *algebraically*.

To wit, for every $N\geqslant1$, the partial sum $$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}{(a_1 +1)\cdots(a_n +1)}$$ is $$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{(a_1 +1)\cdots(a_{n-1} +1)}\left(1-\frac1{a_n+1}\right)$$ hence $$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac1{(a_1 +1)\cdots(a_{n-1} +1)}-\frac1{(a_1 +1)\cdots(a_{n} +1)}\right)$$ that is, by concatenation, $$S_N=1-\frac1{(a_1 +1)\cdots(a_N +1)}$$ and the desired result follows, namely,

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{(a_1 +1)\cdots(a_n +1)}=1-\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{a_n+1}$$

Comment: Sir can you briefly explain the fourth step when $$\sum_1/(a_1+1)(a_2+1)....(a_{n-1} =1$$ i am confused on that part

Comment: Did you note that $$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N(b_{n-1}-b_n)$$ for some well chosen $b_n$s?